# How to send all parameters in a JSON payload when doing a live agent handoff

Tags: parameters, dialogflow-cx

I'm doing a live agent handoff, which allows me to send a JSON to add extra information. I want that information to be $session.params from dialogflow cx. However, I can't write that in the JSON, I get a warning and saving it doesn't persist.

Here's where I tried adding $session.params, replacing the {}. $session.params is a JSON itself, but I can only add literals in this box, I don't know how to add variables from dialogflow..

[image]

Is there a way to send parameter values that are stored in "req.body.sessionInfo.parameters" and $session.params inside the JSON in the picture above?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send some specific params, see Ahmad's answer.

If you want to send the content of the whole session, read the following.

Dialogflow doesn't accept this:

```
{"parameters": $session.params}
```

However, you can do this:

```
{"parameters": "$session.params"}
```

This will put a JSON string under `parameters`.  You will need to `JSON.parse()` it.

Answer (score 0):

You can include parameter references in your custom payload JSON. They should be treated as JSON string values, so wrap them in double quotes. For example:

```
{
  "someField": "$session.params.date"
}
```

source: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#payload